# Communicate with Pixy Cam 2 through SPI and FreeRTOS

Tags: c, spi, freertos

I am trying to communicate with a Pixy 2 Camera using a TI SimpleLink CC3220SF board, and using SPI and FreeRTOS.

I seem to be getting data back from the Pixy Camera, however, it does not seem to be coming back quite as I expect.

For the test code I am doing I should be getting 22 bytes of data, and I am sending a variable with 32 bytes to receive the data, however, it does not seem to start filling with data until the 12th byte.

However, the data that comes back from the 12th byte onward seems to be correct.  I don't know why this is happening any help would be appreciated

I have attached my code below.  Thank you again for any help.

```
SPI_Handle      masterSpi;
SPI_Params      spiParams;
SPI_Transaction transaction;
uint32_t        i;
bool            transferOK;
uint8_t versionRequest[] = {0xae, 0xc1, 0x0e, 0x00};
uint8_t j, recvBuf[32];

SPI_Params_init(&spiParams);
spiParams.frameFormat = SPI_POL1_PHA1;
spiParams.bitRate = 100000;
masterSpi = SPI_open(CONFIG_SPI_MASTER, &spiParams);
if (masterSpi == NULL) {
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Error initializing master SPI\n");
    while (1);
}
else {
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Master SPI initialized\n");
}

transaction.count = 32;
transaction.txBuf = (void *) versionRequest;
transaction.rxBuf = (void *) recvBuf;

transferOK = SPI_transfer(masterSpi, &transaction);
if (transferOK) {
    for (j=0; j<22; j++)
        Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "%hhu: 0x%hhx\n", j, recvBuf[j]);
}
else {
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Unsuccessful master SPI transfer");
}

SPI_close(masterSpi);

Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "\nDone");

return (NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's review the 
[serial protocol](https://docs.pixycam.com/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:v2:i_don-27t_see_my_controller_supported_what_do_i_do#the-serial-protocol)
of Pixy 2:

- `versionRequest[0] == 0xae`/`versionRequest[1] == 0xc1` => no checksum used.
- `versionRequest[2] == 0x0e` => "version request", as variable name suggests.
- `versionRequest[3] == 0x00` => no request payload data, frame is over after 4th byte.

Your request looks correct to me, plus it matches the proposition from the Pixy2 integration side.

---

There is one fundamental difference among serial protocols that the guide doesn't discuss at all: 
While TX/RX communication in the UART is *a*synchronous (like "A" in U*A*RT"), in SPI communication both directions (MOSI/MISO) refer to a common clock signal (SCK).
That is, the master must trigger the clock in order to receive further data until the request-response sequence is complete.
The slave needs some latency until it can start transmitting its response:

- For physical reasons, this is at least one byte.
- For logical reasons, it can only start when it received enough information out of the request (here: the first three bytes, or the entire request).
- For technical reasons, it may need some additional cycles for its internal processing (e.g., reading out data from an internal flash memory with the corresponding latency).

Sadly, the online documentation to the protocol doesn't comment on how many cycles the slave response shall take until it starts (at least, as far as I see).

---

Therefore, you should proceed the following way (in my personal opinion):

1. Verify that the response data you receive are compatible with the response contents in documentation:

   ```
   0xaf // first byte of checksum_sync (little endian -> least-significant byte first)
   0xc1 // second byte of checksum_sync
   0x0f // this is the version response type
   0x10 // data_length is 0x10 (16) bytes 
   0x0d // first byte of data checksum (little endian -> least-significant byte first)
   0x03 // second byte of data checksum
   0x00 // first byte of hardware version (little endian -> least-significant byte first)
   0x22 // second byte of hardware version
   0x03 // firmware major version number
   0x00 // firmware minor version number
   0x0a // first byte of firmware build number (little endian -> least-significant byte first)
   0x00 // second byte of firmware build number
   0x67 // byte 0 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x65 // byte 1 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x6e // byte 2 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x65 // byte 3 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x72 // byte 4 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x61 // byte 5 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x6c // byte 6 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x00 // byte 7 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x00 // byte 8 of firmware type ASCII string
   0x00 // byte 9 of firmware type ASCII string
   ```

   Especially, you should verify in the first four non-zero bytes that the response frame has the expected type and the number of bytes is as expected (0x10 = sixteen).
2. If the first four bytes of the response frame header match, check what happens if you "wait" and transfer additional zero bytes to the SPI in order to get back further response bytes.
   You should receive the expected number of bytes (22).
   For every following byte, the slave should send you either fixed bits (0x00 or 0xFF bytes) or repeat the last byte again and again (if the slave is fairly dumb).

   Using that expected number of bytes starting from the first header byte, you can evaluate the 16-bit checksum (5th/6th byte, little-endian) over the payload (7th to 22nd byte) and see whether it matches.
   If yes, I'd take the pragmatic approach and use this response.
   The uncomfortable implication is that this means you have to wait for/synchronize to the header of any response frame.
3. The next level would be to read the 
   [firmware](https://github.com/charmedlabs/pixy2),
   taking into account the
   [schematics and controller reference manuals](http://cmucam.org/projects/cmucam5/documents), which corresponds to a large part of reverse engineering.

**Edit:**

PS: As the documentation states in the first section of
[this page](https://docs.pixycam.com/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:v2:protocol_reference),
the Pixy2 release is now using a request-response protocol after the previous one broadcasted its data spontaneously.
This might mean that the changed protocol is quite new and the documentation/specification is not complete yet...

PPS: [This thread](https://forum.pixycam.com/t/pixy-2-interfacing-via-spi-using-stm32f7/6202/10)
in the Pixy forum deals with a similar problem.
The asker reports

> While receiving version from pixy2 i noticed that it sends first 9 bytes as garbage. [...]

This is not in line with your finding (11 bytes of garbage instead...), but maybe the difference is due to a different SPI clock setting.